# Does a class survey count as a random sampling?

Tags: sampling, survey, survey-sampling

If we had a class of 200 people and we made a survey in which anyone in the class can choose to participate or not, does this count as random sampling?

I feel like it's not, but I can't put it into words why it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not* random sampling, because people have a free and possibly biased choice, or reason, to not participate. Put differently, the people opting-in are possibly different (in relevant characteristics) from those opting-out.

---

See also [Wikipedia: self-selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-selection_bias).